# /usr partition filled up, need to make it larger or mount it somewhere else

Tags: linux, freebsd, partition, disk-usage

I have 160 GBhdd. I have `ubuntu` on about 30GB and Rest is `PC-BSD` 9.0.

On PC-BSD, my /usr is about 11GB and that is all used up. I realize that when I try to install ubuntu inside `VirtualBox`. I need 15GB at least.

I do not understand how 11GB became /usr partition's limit. I do not recall making any such decision while installation.

BTW, for now, to solve my problem, here is output of `gpart`. How can I extend /usr?

OR, how can I make the home dirs which are now part of /usr/home separate from /usr?

```
[root@pcbsd] ~# gpart show
=>       63  312581745  ada0  MBR  (149G)
         63    2002879        - free -  (978M)
    2002942   60825602     2  ebr  (29G)
   62828544    6000640     1  linux-data  (2.9G)
   68829184       9341        - free -  (4.6M)
   68838525  243738180     3  freebsd  [active]  (116G)
  312576705       5103        - free -  (2.5M)

=>       0  60825602  ada0s2  EBR  (29G)
         0   7997442       1  linux-swap  (3.8G)
   7997442  48828416  126944  linux-data  (23G)
  56825858      1230          - free -  (615k)
  56827088   3998514  902018  linux-data  (1.9G)

=>        0  243738180  ada0s3  BSD  (116G)
          0    4194304       1  freebsd-ufs  (2.0G)
    4194304    8101888       2  freebsd-swap  (3.9G)
   12296192    4194304       4  freebsd-ufs  (2.0G)
   16490496  227247684       5  freebsd-ufs  (108G)

[root@pcbsd] ~# df -k
Filesystem         1024-blocks     Used    Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/label/rootfs0     2063900   570260  1328528    30%    /
devfs                        1        1        0   100%    /dev
/dev/label/var0        2063900   207488  1691300    11%    /var
/dev/label/usr0      111838140 11911712 90979380    12%    /usr
procfs                       4        4        0   100%    /proc
linprocfs                    4        4        0   100%    /compat/linux/proc
```

[image: Disk Usage Analyzer for entire disk]

[image: Disk Usage Analyzer for /usr which is filling up]

Comment: Where do you see an 11GB filesystem? Or a nearly-full one? Your `/usr` is 108GB with 90GB free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any 11GB partitions in your `gpart` output. `/root` is a home directory for user "root" and usually located on `/` partition. Why do you need 15GB on `/root`? On FreeBSD `/home` is usually symlinked to `/usr/home` (unless there is separate `/home` partition) and uses all available disk space left after `/` and `/var`.

Comment: I've just added "disk usage analyzer" screenshot. I am not sure how these partitions are created.